# Does $A > B$ imply $A^2 > B^2$

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

It is a surprising fact that the statement
$$A > B \implies \mathcal{P}(A) > \mathcal{P}(B)$$ is undecidable in $\mathrm{ZFC}$.

I want to ask a similar question: Assume $A > B$. Does it follow that $A^2 > B^2$?

Remark: $\mathcal{P}(A)$, as usual, denotes the power set of $A$. Also, we define $A > B$ to mean: there exists an injection $B\to A$ but no bijection between these two sets. $A^2$ is an abbreviation for $A\times A$.

Comment: Yes, quite sure.

Comment: @CameronBuie Unfortunately choice doesn't help us here.

Comment: I wonder if this is true without Choice ...

Comment: @Noah: Nope. You can find examples in Jech's Axiom of Choice, over at Chapter 11.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Neat, thanks!

Comment: @Noah: See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all $A$ of infinite cardinality we have $A \sim A^2$, i.e. there is a bijection $A \to A^2$ and hence, assuming $A > B$ are both infinite:
$$
A^2 \sim A > B \sim B^2
$$
and thus
$$
A^2 > B^2.
$$

---

The fact that we have $A \sim A^2$ for all infinite $A$ is covered in any introductory book on set theory. [E.g. Kunen's [Set Theory](https://www.amazon.de/Set-Theory-Studies-Logic-Mathematical/dp/1848900503/ref=sr_1_1?s=books-intl-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1507813730&sr=1-1&keywords=kunen+set+theory), Jech's [Set Theory](https://www.amazon.de/Set-Theory-Millennium-Monographs-Mathematics/dp/3642078990/ref=sr_1_1?s=books-intl-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1507813755&sr=1-1&keywords=jech+set+theory), Schindler's [Set Theory: Exploring Independence and Truth](https://www.amazon.de/Set-Theory-Exploring-Independence-Universitext/dp/3319067249), ...] It follows, for example, from a basic observation of Gödel's pairing function and doesn't rely on the axiom of choice as long as we are only talking about well-orderable sets $A,B$. However, for general $A$ that don't admit a wellorder in $\mathrm{ZF}$, we may have $A \not \sim A^2$.

Comment: But it is not necessarily the case that a set which cannot be well ordered is smaller than its square. There are many sets which provably equipotent with their squares, even if they are not well orderable. The reals, for example.

Comment: @Asaf That's why I said "*for general $A$*... *we may*..." I didn't mean to imply that being well-orderable is equivalent to be equipotent with ones square.

Comment: Yeah I just wanted to make this crystal clear.

Comment: @Asaf Yeah, I think I could've been a bit clearer about that point. Thanks for your input!

Comment: See my answer... :)

Answer (score 3):

The statement $|A| > |B| \implies |\mathcal P(A)| > |\mathcal P(B)|$ is not provable in ZFC in general, but it certainly is provable in many specific cases, including for $|A|$ finite.

For $|B|$ finite, you can prove $|A| > |B| \implies |A|^2 > |B|^2$ easily as well, while for all infinite $A$, we have $|A| = |A|^2$ in ZFC, so that $|A| > |B| \implies |A|^2 > |B|^2$ trivially.

Comment: Other than the finite case, there's absolutely nothing you can say in general. Sure, there is always a larger set with a larger power set, but that's not saying much. Assuming ZFC, given any cardinal $\kappa$, we can find a cardinal-preserving extension to the universe where $2^\kappa=2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Perhaps "many" is a big exaggeration, but the example I had in mind was the one I would guess most people are most familiar with, namely $|\mathbb R| > |\mathbb N|$.

Answer (score 3):

While it wasn't explicitly asked, I feel it's worth mentioning, as there was some question about this in the comments.

> **Theorem.** $\sf ZF$ proves that $A<B\to A^2<B^2$ implies the axiom of choice.

*Proof.*

Recall Tarski's lemma, if $\lambda$ is an well-ordered cardinal and $x$ is any set, then $|X|+\lambda=|X|\cdot\lambda$ implies that $|X|$ is comparable with $\lambda$.

**Lemma 1.** Suppose that $x=|X|$ and $y=|X|$ are cardinals of non-empty sets such that $x^2=x$ and $y^2=y$, then $(x+y)^2=xy$.

*Proof of Lemma 1.* First note that if $x^2=x$, then $x+x=x+1=x$. Next, we have the following: $$(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2=x+xy+y.$$
But since $x+1=x$ and $y+1=y$, we get: $$xy=(x+1)(y+1)=xy+x+y+1=xy+x+y=(x+y)^2.\quad\square$$

Next, suppose that $X$ is any set, then $X^\omega$ satisfies that $|(X^\omega)^2|=|X^\omega|$, and $\lambda=\aleph(X^\omega)$—the least infinite cardinal which cannot be injectively mapped into $X^\omega$—satisfies this also. Let $A=X^\omega+\lambda$ and $B=X^\omega\times\lambda$.

If $|A|<|B|$, then by the assumption $|A|^2<|B|^2$. But this contradicts Lemma 1. Therefore $|A|=|B|$, and then by Tarski's lemma it has to be the case that $X^\omega$ can be well-ordered, and thus $X$ can be well-ordered as well.$\quad\square$

Comment: With regards to the Highlander pub in Vienna for supplying the Guinness needed for this train of thoughts.

Comment: "Highlander pub" seems appropriate...

Comment: Because there can be only one?

Comment: Actually, everytime I read about weird results under the failure of $\mathrm{CH}$, I think to myself: "Tonight you sleep in hell." - That's why I thought "Highlander pub" was appropriate.

Comment: Admittedly, this brings to mind 300 more than it does Highlander. "Ready your breakfast and eat hearty... for tonight we dine in hell!" (by the most Scottish Greek king to ever appear in cinema).

Comment: Well, but there wasn't exactly a reference to 300 here, was there?

Comment: No, we're referencing Guinness. Of which I wish there were 300... :P